# Wordpress coaching - schedules for individual athlets solution?

Tags: wordpress

I am spinning in circles trying to accomplish this.. I think I might be overlooking something.. maybe not, any help would be greatly appreciated?

I am working on a coaching website where I have 10 or more athletes. I need a solution where ( me as a coach ) can individualize each athlete and upload different schedules/training for each of my athletes??

So, maybe one day I can upload PDF training to Athlete 1, and then at the same time, I can upload a different training to Athlete 2.. and then Athlete 1 can log in and will only see his/her training and no one else's training..? So, it would be very individualized per POST -- but how to accomplish when an athlete logs in only sees their training.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are going to need to start with users. Add a user for each of your corresponding athletes as logins.

If you fancy really getting knee deep in code, write a plugin. If not, find a document management plugin that offers support for users. Check some of these. Including the user access manager which might offer the same sort of functionality.

http://www.jeangalea.com/wordpress/wordpress-document-management-plugins/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-access-manager/